# Column list with links - items move down on click in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, column-count

Column lists in Chrome have an odd bug: When you click the first link in a 1+ column (not the first column) then the item moves the column down by ~5px.

Is this a bug? Can I prevent it with some CSS rules?

Tested Chrome version: 39.0.2171.71 m

Test this in Chrome [(fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/fa4auxkr/3/):

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of Chrome 39](https://crbug.com/388666), anchor elements become focused upon click, i.e. the `onfocus` event gets triggered and the `:focus` style gets applied.

Because `:focus` is now enabled when you click on the link, the default user agent style gets applied as well, i.e.

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

This outline should not influence the multi-column rendering<s>, but it does anyway, which *is*  a bug</s> ([fixed](https://crbug.com/439820)).

To fix the problem, simply add `outline:0;` to the `a` selector (http://jsfiddle.net/fa4auxkr/4/):

```
ul a {
    outline: none;
}
```

Note that the outline is used for accessibility, so don't apply this rule without reason.

Comment: Very interesting, any idea why `display: block` prevents this?

Comment: @misterManSam I don't know, I'm not familiar with the implementation of multi-columns.

Comment: Thanks, `outline:none;` seems the safest. `ul li a { display:inline-block; }` would do aswell.

Comment: `block` fixes it, but the entire width of the column becomes clickable since it is a `block` element. The original problem still exists with `inline-block`. `outline: none` accomplishes this best.

Comment: `outline:none` makes it less accessible. Some people can't use mouse and they select links with Tab (or similar way), and the outline is there for them to see the selection move.

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting behaviour! Looks like something to do with the children having `display: inline` when their parents are in a column.

Changing the `<a>` to `display: block` fixes the issue.

### No Bug Example

First list has this jumpy behaviour. Second list with display block links, doesn't have the jumping behaviour.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
.noJump a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is the jump problem</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">My siblings like to jump</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I love Jumping!</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I love Jumping!</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>This has the jumped problem fixed with display: block</h2>
<ul class="noJump">
  <li><a href="#">No Jump</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">No Jump</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">No Jump</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```