# column of icons in bootstrap v4

Tags: flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I have a simple column of icons using flexbox in bootstrap v4.  It comes up fine, but if you then click on an icon, the position changes slightly.  Seems to happen only in chrome.  Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/lenb/shr8bk89/10/
    ` 
HTML:

```
<body>


    <div id='no'>

      <div id='minus' class="icon" title="Not special.">
        <a href="#" id="nHeart">
          <img class="img icon" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/Not.svg" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id='plus' class="icon" title="Loving it!">
        <a href="#" id="heart1">
          <img class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/red-304570-1.svg" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id='comment-button-div' class="icon" title="Click for comments">
        <a class="comment-page" data-toggle="modal">
          <img class="img" id='comment-button' src="http://gps-photo.org/images/comments-97860-3.svg" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id='info-div1' class="icon" title='Information'>
        <a class="info-page" data-toggle="modal">
          <img id="info1" class="img" src="http://gps-photo.org/images/information-39064-2.svg" />
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous"> 


   #removal {
     border-color: black;
     border-top: 10rem;
   }

   html,
   body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }



   #no {
     padding: 1rem;
     display: flex;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
     -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     align-content: space-between;
     -webkit-align-content: space-between;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
   }

   .icon {
     margin: auto;
     flex-grow: 1;
     flex-basis: auto;
   }


   /* // next is for images */
   .img {
     width: 8vmin;
   }

 /*   // stuff living in #no */
   #info-div1 {
     order: 3;
     -webkit-order: 3;
   }

   #minus {
     order: 0;
     -webkit-order: 0;
   }

   #plus {
     order: 1;
     -webkit-order: 1;
   }

   #comment-button-div {
     order: 2;
     -webkit-order: 2;
   }


     #no {
       flex-direction: column;
       -webkit-flex-direction: column;
       height: 100%;
       max-width: 10rem;
       order: 0;
       -webkit-order: 0;
     }
```

I see no reason why the positioning should change.

Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: In the fiddle, consider removing the scripts in both panes. You can add the bootstrap link as an External Resource.

Comment: Removed links as suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/lenb/shr8bk89/12/

Comment: Ok. But when you click on an icon, nothing happens. Are you able to reproduce the problem in the demo?

Comment: When I click on an icon (in chrome) the icons move.  On firefox they don't.  I don't think they should move.  Looks like a bug in chrome to me, but if so, I don't know how to proceed.  Outside of the fiddle, I get the same behavior.  It differs on chrome and firefox.

Comment: I'm on Chrome and nothing is happening. But I think I know what the problem is. When you click, the icons move vertically? Like toward the top of the page?

Comment: Yes.  They get closer together.

Comment: Well, like I said, I'm not seeing any movement here on click. However, when you use a `#` symbol in an anchor tag, this takes the page to the top.

Comment: So while you're testing, if you don't want to see any page movement, consider replacing `<a href="#" ... >` with `<a href="javascript:void(0)" ... >`.

Comment: And you are using chrome?  I've tried chrome-unstable and running incognito.  I get the same behavior on the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/lenb/shr8bk89/13/).  Change in the vertical separation.  I see the same behavior on the actual page (it is part of gps-photo.org).  On chrome, clicking on an icon changes vertical separation; in firefox, not.

Comment: Both the fiddle and your web page work fine for me on Chrome. No movement of icons, not even slightly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column list with links - items move down on click in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346943/column-list-with-links-items-move-down-on-click-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Using normalize.css as the 1st to load helps to normalize vertical alignment for Chrome